# Error in Email with php script by Cron Job

Tags: php, mysql

I have database with last_logoff_date. I recently added new column last_login_date. I am trying to send email to members whose last_login_date is greater than 10 days and less than 120 days. As I have created last_login_date column recently with timestamp atrribute, every row is set as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 by default, and now onwards when member get login to site, current timestamp is added to this field.
Now with below code, email is getting send to members with last_login_date 0000-00-00 also and even to members logged in before 1 day too.

In short, email gets delivered to all memebrs with member_status=1 irrespective of last_login_date...

I could not find out the error.
This php is script is used for cronjob.

My Code is as follows..

```
 <?php
 include("db1.php");
 require("class.phpmailer.php");
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $login_check=mysql_query("select * from table name where member_status= '1' AND last_login_date != '0000-00-00' ");
 while($datelogin=mysql_fetch_array($login_check)){ 
     mysql_query("select * from table name WHERE reg_id =".$datelogin['reg_id']);   

 $date1= date("Y-m-d");
 $date2=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($datelogin['last_login_date'])); 
 $dateDiff = strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2);
 $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));

     if($fullDays >= 10 && $fullDays <= 121){   

 ob_start();
 ?>

 email  data.....

 <?
 $body=ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean ();    
 ........
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of the second query.

Comment: ok. but my question is, email gets delivered to members with last_login_date less than 10 days and gretaer than 120 days too.

Comment: What's the value of `$dateDiff`?

Comment: I used $dateDiff to echo actual Days For last Login in Email.

Comment: And when you echoed `$dateDiff`, what did you see in the cases where you didn't expect it to send mail?

Comment: i saw 735763 Days when last_login_date = 0000-00-00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE member_status = '1'
AND last_login_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 120 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank You Sir for best solution. It worked for me.I used $dateDiff to echo actual Days For last Login in Email.